# Display AirPlay icon without Airplay device?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm trying to add an AirPlay button to my app and used the following code:

```
MPVolumeView *volumeView = [ [MPVolumeView alloc] init] ;
[volumeView setShowsVolumeSlider:NO];
[volumeView sizeToFit];          
aCell.accessoryView = volumeView;
```

I can't get it to display and I'm assuming it's because I don't have an AirPlay enabled device. Is there anyway I can get the icon to display for testing purposes? I need to see if it will be positioned correctly.

Thank you!

Comment: airplay button will be shown when any other sourrounding devices are ready for airplay display

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run Airfoil Speakers on your mac, so when your phone and your computer are on the same wireless network, your app will display the airplay button. [Airfoil Speakers](http://rogueamoeba.com/airfoil/speakers.php)